# Operating system encryption of a Virtual Machine

Tags: encryption, operating-systems, virtualization, veracrypt

I am a MacBook Pro user but sometimes I need to manage very sensitive data on Windows Seven. I am running Windows Seven on a virtual machine using Parallels Desktop v10.2.1. This software already has (in the security tab) an encryption option that I already use but, since I haven't found any information on how this method works (and how secure it is), I would like to proceed in another way.

I would like to have my VM encrypted and isolated (no shared files have to be saved on Mac). I tried the Operating System Encryption using Veracrypt from Windows directly but I got stuck when the software asks me to burn a recovery CD because my MacBook doesn't have CD reader/writer.

Any suggestion on how to bypass this problem or solve it in any other secure way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Windows 7 version you have, you could use the built-in Windows BitLocker.

But please notice that this would be an additional encryption within the VM and not from your Mac's point of view.

See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835565(v=ws.10).aspx) for a more detailed description and a step by step guide for BitLocker